# how to change color depth to 32 bit?

Tags: 13.04

I have Ubuntu 13.04 amd 64 and I want to change color depth to 32 bit and i tried to change /etc/X11/xorg.conf but i think it didn't work 
please for help .

hint : my graphic card is intel G41

Comment: The most deep screen color depth is 24 bit, but images can be of 32-bit depth because they may contain alpha-channel. What is your color depth now? If it's already 24-bit, you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

There is no such thing as 32-bit colors, at least when it comes to displays. Not even when Microsoft likes to call their 24-bit color mode a "32-bit" mode.

24-bit colors give you 8 bits per color channel, totaling 16,7 million colors (2^8 * 2^8 * 2^8 = ). That's way more than what most LCD displays are able to handle (in fact most consumer-grade LCD panels are really only able to display 18-bit colors)

Pictures and graphics can have 32-bit colors, in which case the last 8 bits are used for Alpha channel (transparency). As long as out displays can't become transparent they have no need for those last 8 bits.

More reading see [Color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Forums</sup>

Comment: No, it's not true! The 32-bit color mode to sample more focus, more natural when in 24bit mode.
When we look at the Ubuntu desktop, we have a feeling, in color, it does not have the necessary focus and transparency.
Maybe in the future, engineers source code want to work to correct this problem, leaving aside obstinacy!